# Writing Body Parser with Security Trait for multipartFormData, Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to upload an image at the same time when I submit the form, after some research I tried using mutlipartFormData to accomplish the feat.
This is my form submission function header after following the tutorials.

```
def insert = withInsert(parse.multipartFormData) { username => implicit request =>
```

I used security trait to check for user (withUser), login time (withAuth) and permission (withInsert)

```
def withUser(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
        Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
          Action(request => f(user)(request))
        }
    }

def withAuth(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = withUser { user => request =>
    var timestamp = request.session.get("timestamp")
    timestamp.map { timestamp =>
        if(System.currentTimeMillis - timestamp.toLong < (3600*1000))
            f(user)(request)
        else
            onUnauthorized(request)
    }
    .getOrElse{
        onUnauthorized(request)
    }
}

def withInsert[A](p: BodyParser[A])(f: String => Request[A] => Result) = withAuth { username => request =>

        val permission = User.checkAuth("Page", username)

        if(permission.page_insert == 1)
            Action(p)(request => f(username)(request))
         else
            onPermissionDenied(request)
    }

def onPermissionDenied(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Page.index)
```

As the insert function needed a body parser, I modified the (withInsert) trait to support a body parser. But, then I got a compile error on this line.

```
Action(p)(request => f(username)(request))

type mismatch; found : play.api.mvc.Action[A] required: play.api.mvc.Result
```

I'm quite lost to what is wrong here, any help is greatly appreciated.

### Edit:

I've tried to do exactly what the tutorial did, abandoning the usage of withAuth on the security trait

```
def withInsert[A](p: BodyParser[A])(f: String => Request[A] => Result) = { 
        Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
            val permission = User.checkAuth("Page", user)

            if(permission.page_insert == 1)
                Action(p)(request => f(user)(request))
            else
                onPermissionDenied(request)
        }
    }
```

this code results in another compile error on the same line, but with different error

```
not found: value request
```

After removing the permission checking, it returns no compile error.

```
def withInsert[A](p: BodyParser[A])(f: String => Request[A] => Result) = { 
        Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
            Action(p)(request => f(user)(request))
        }
    }
```

But I need the program to check for permission before running functions and not just username (Current user has logged in or not). Is there a way to do this?
I need a workaround so that I could apply the permission checking and the body parser to the trait.

Comment: Could you show how `withInsert` is used?

Comment: withInsert is used in the insert function (first code block)